# PowerBI calculating sales for the specific period

Tags: powerbi, dax

[New Challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U1mm.png)
So in the picture i want to have three columns. Customer, Revenue in the first 12 Months (your formula) and the last month of revenue from this formula. (Ideally, also the first month of revenue from this formula) Both columns for 1st and last revenue months in format like : March 2023

I have

Fact Table: Sales. Columns: Customer, sales Value, Date
Dim Table : Dates

In the report slicers are : Year and Customer

Please open the link to my one drive.

1). Customer A's revenue starts in January 2024 and i need to calculate the total for the first 12 months of revenue only. I dont wanna see this customer in 2025 when i slice by year.
2). Customer's B revenue starts in July 2024. I need data displayed till July 2025 and no data displayed afterwards.

[SampleData](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nyw4gNnR_K3o-o1k49oXovYOYPUaK6e5?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Add some sample data from both table and then your required presentation based on slicer value.

Comment: hi! ive added the sample data and what i am trying to achieve. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 12 months will show Customer B till June'24 and not July'24, yes? Otherwise, you will see Customer A in January'24.

Create a Measure along the lines of:

```
First 12 Month Revenue = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('Sales'[Customer ]),
    (
      var startRevenue = CALCULATE(MIN('Sales'[Date]), ALLEXCEPT('Sales', 'Sales'[Customer ]), NOT ISBLANK('Sales'[Revenue]))
      var endRevenue = DATE(YEAR(startRevenue) + 1, MONTH(startRevenue), DAY(startRevenue))
      return
        CALCULATE(
          SUM('Sales'[Revenue]),
          KEEPFILTERS('Dates'[FullDateAlternateKey] < endRevenue)
        )
    )
  )
```

---

Additional expressions for first and last date.

```
First 12 Month Revenue First Date = 
  MINX(
    DISTINCT('Sales'[Customer ]),
    CALCULATE(MIN('Sales'[Date]), ALLEXCEPT('Sales', 'Sales'[Customer ]), NOT ISBLANK('Sales'[Revenue]))
  )


First 12 Month Revenue Last Date = 
  MAXX(
    DISTINCT('Sales'[Customer ]),
    (
      var startRevenue = CALCULATE(MIN('Sales'[Date]), ALLEXCEPT('Sales', 'Sales'[Customer ]), NOT ISBLANK('Sales'[Revenue]))
      var endRevenue = DATE(YEAR(startRevenue) + 1, MONTH(startRevenue), DAY(startRevenue))
      return
        CALCULATE(
          MAX('Sales'[Date]),
          'Dates'[FullDateAlternateKey] < endRevenue,
          NOT ISBLANK('Sales'[Revenue])
        )
    )
  )
```

These both will return a date, you can then format these in `Format` under `Measure tools` in the ribbon.

Comment: hi! Yes, Sam. exactly! im gonna give it a try

Comment: hey, i think it worked! thank you very much! I unfortunately cannot vote up due to points, but i tried :)

Comment: Glad it worked, please help mark the answer as Accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons.

Comment: hi Sam. sorry for bothering again. is there a way to change the formula so that I have in the matrix
Customer
Total Revenue for the first 12 months
Last Date of the revenue within this 12 months span. 

I want to keep it simple, without columns for months.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Could you update the question or add a visual representation of what you are after.

Comment: hey! I posted a new screenshot "new challenge". the problem i am facing is that the LastRevenue column for the last revenue month in my screenshot is not correct, because it is not coming from the formula you created.

Comment: Update answer above with the additional asks.